# Have vs.net automatically execute xsd.exe everytime time xsd is modified

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

In the past, I have used XSD.exe to create c# classes from an xsd.  Today, I added an XSD to VS.NET 2008 SP1 and it automatically generated a dataset from my xsd, slick but I don't want a dataset.  Is there a way to have vs.net automatically execute xsd.exe each time I modify my xsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best bet would be to run xsd.exe as a pre-build event, and setting the build action for your XSD to "None".

Comment: But then you haven't generated files automaticly included in project for compile.

Comment: So the generated classes wil not be compiled :).

Answer (score 1):

Select the *.xsd file, open Properties Window (F4 key) and delete "Custom Tool" and "Custom Tool Namespace". This will remove the "DataSet" issue.

The "c# class from an xsd" issue can be solved by another custom tool. Look at [XsdCondeGenTool](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2004/05/14/XsdCodeGenTool.aspx) - there is sample, how to do it.

Comment: XSDCodeGenerator's XSDGenerator.CustomTool is a good example of how to register a .net tool, but the XSDGenerator library is to me a simple example of how XSD.exe works and not a great xsd->c# tool in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Whether xsd.exe generates datasets or classes depends on the command line arguments.  Extract from xsd /?:

> /classes
>       Generate classes for this schema. Short form is '/c'.
>
> /dataset
>       Generate sub-classed DataSet for this schema. Short form is '/d'.

A pre-build event could help with updating your auto generated classes when the schema changes.  You might want to consider [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) instead.  Nant is a port for .Net of the Java build script Ant.  With Nant you can create reasonably complex build scripts that will be able to invoke xsd.exe.  I also imagine they could help call out to some scripts that could update your project file to reference the xsd generated classes (not something I've done but very doable I would think).